# I want to compile Boost 1.70 with Clang 60 on Centos 7

Tags: boost, llvm, centos7, clang++, llvm-clang

I want to try another C++ compiler (CLang 6) but I'm depending on Boost. How do I get Boost installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While compiling Boost with toolset=clang is easily implemented with a PR on the ansible-role https://github.com/dockpack/base_boost/pull/24, the problem really is [where to get Clang 6 for Centos 7](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=70149)?

> Note: Since the November 2018 release, Red Hat’s Clang/LLVM package
>   naming convention has changed so that the Red Hat version number now
>   reflects the upstream version. The llvm-toolset-7packages (without the
>   dot zero), are based on Clang/LLVM 5.0. The new package name for
>   Clang/LLVM 7.0 is llvm-toolset-7.0 (seven dot zero). Although this
>   might seem confusing now, hopefully it will make things easier for
>   everyone going forward.

I'm interested in llvm-toolset-6.0 which is available for RHEL 7, but can't be found in
 CentOS 7.

**Springdale Linux** usually rebuilds SCL stuff much faster then the CentOS Software Collections SIG.

llvm-toolset-7 contains LLVM 5.0.1.

llvm-toolset-6.0 contains LLVM 6.

llvm-toolset-7.0 contains LLVM 7.

```
[SCL-core]
name=Springdale SCL Base $releasever - $basearch
mirrorlist=http://springdale.princeton.edu/data/springdale/SCL/$releasever/$basearch/mirrorlist
#baseurl=http://springdale.princeton.edu/data/springdale/SCL/$releasever/$basearch
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-springdale
```